# Encryption over handheld transceiver

Tags: united-states, privacy, encryption, radio, fcc

I'm aware that encryption of amateur radio communications is prohibited (or rather, any technique to make the message unreadable is). Does this apply to handheld transceivers ("Walkie-Talkies")?

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain how I should improve this question?

Comment: Seems fine to me (and an interesting question). I guess it could be improved by citing the regulation/law that bans encryption, but that's really just icing on the cake, in my opinion.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but why would there be any difference between amateur radios and handheld transceivers?

Comment: @RockApe I don't know, but I've always heard that encryption for amateur radio is a big no-no, but I've also heard "encrypted walkie-talkie" a number of times not once with any claims that such a thing is illegal.

Comment: It may be something to do with the licencing requirements for certain frequencies. Have you asked over at [RadioSE](https://ham.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @RockApe From a quick web search, I think the law is 47 CFR § 97.309 (4)(b).

Comment: @RockApe, amateur operators are licensed.  People using handheld transceivers are generally operating under one of the exemptions to licensing.

Comment: @RockApe There are quite a few differences between amateur radio and the handheld units OP is referring to including power output, hardware choices, operating bands. There are probably more differences in the law than similarities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handheld transceivers are usually operated under some portion of [47 CFR 95 (Personal Radio Services)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/part-95).  Typically, this is [subpart B (Family Radio Service)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/part-95/subpart-B) or [subpart D (CB Radio Service)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/part-95/subpart-D); occasionally it's [subpart E (General Mobile Radio Service](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/part-95/subpart-E).

CB Radio Service [only permits plain-language voice communication](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/95.931).  Not only is encryption prohibited, using coded language is also forbidden (eg. the Navajo code talkers would be forbidden to communicate over CB radio).

Family Radio Service is slightly more permissive, [permitting certain data transmissions in addition to voice](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/95.531), and it doesn't have the requirement of plain language.  However, encryption is forbidden under the general [prohibition of voice-obscuring features](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/95.381) for Part 95 operation.

General Mobile Radio Service [has a general prohibition on coded messages or messages with hidden meanings](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/95.1733), making it possibly even more restrictive than CB radio's "plain language" requirement.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but does this mean that "Personal Radio Services" permit encryption?

Comment: "Personal Radio Services" is a very broad grouping.  Some of the subparts (eg. subpart H, "Wireless Medical Telemetry Service") have no restrictions on encryption, but something like a wireless heart-rate monitor isn't exactly a "handheld transceiver".

Comment: So I can conclude that it is not legal to transmit "coded language" over walkie talkie?

Comment: Unless you've got a license that lets you do so, no.  In virtually every situation in the US, the rules for what you can do with a radio aren't determined by what device you're using, but by what license or license exception you're operating under.